# how to resize image without affecting its resolution in ios

Tags: ios, image

I have an image view in which I have set image.It works fine if the size of image and image view is almost same. But what if we change the device, Image view is  inc in size but the image gets stretched. I am unable to find any way to resize this image such that the image is not affected by the size of image view and at the same time remain centralized also. Also resolution of the image should not be affected.

Comment: aspect fit for Imageview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```

or

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

Aspect Fit: Will size your image until the whole image will fit within your UIImageView Box. Thats why you are left with the extra space on top and bottom.

Aspect Fill: Will size your image proportionally until the whole UIImageView is full of your image. So that is why you see clipping of your image. It will actually size it proportionally to make sure there is no blank space left in your imageview.

In a nutshell: Aspect Fit makes sure your whole image is visible proportionally. Aspect Fill will make sure there is no space left in the imageview while sizing your image proportionally.

so it is upon you what you can compromise.
a rendom google image for example.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this  `imageViewName.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

as per docs This  option is used to scale the content to fit the size of the view by maintaining the aspect ratio